# Mathematica gives the answer of a limit as DirectedInfinity[Sin[x/y]]; does this mean that the limit does not exist?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions

I have a typical real function $f(x,y;z)$ where $z>0$ is a real variable and $x,y>0$ are two real parameters; I use Mathematica to compute the limit
$$ \lim_{z\to\frac{\pi}x} f(x,y;z) $$
and Mathematica gives the answer

```
Limit[ f(x,y;z) , z->  Pi/x]
(*DirectedInfinity[Sin[x/y]]*)
```

I appreciate it if someone kindly explains what this answer means; does it mean that the limit is complex and does not exist?

Comment: It means that the limit tends towards infinity, and it has the same direction in the complex plane as `Sin[x/y]`. So if `Sin[x/y]` is positive, it's positive infinity. If it's negative, it's negative infinity. If it's some complex value, it's an infinity in that specific complex direction.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code instead of TeX code.

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you for your comment. But my question only concerns the concept "DirectedInfinity[.]"

Comment: @eyorble Thanks; so, since $\sin\frac xy$ is real, then, the limit exists, it is either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, am I right?

Comment: @sar96  In this forum, TeX is not good as Mathematica code.

Comment: A caution: `Sin[x/y]` doesn't need to be real if `x` and `y` can be complex or `y` can be 0, and if `Sin[x/y]` is 0 then you need to look into it further to be sure. Otherwise yes.

Comment: @eyorble Thanks; as I have written in the question, $x,y>0$ and real, so, the limit exists but goes to infinity.

Comment: Except potentially where $k \in \mathbb{Z}, x/y = k \pi$, since then $\sin (x/y) = 0$ and further analysis is required, if we're being as precise as possible. The result in that case may still be a positive or negative infinity or it may be an indeterminate value, haven't looked into it enough to be sure and it may depend on the original problem.

Comment: `DirectedInfinity[u]` means the limit is infinite, which normally means the limit does not exist. Other definitions of "exist" exist.

Comment: It is difficult to impossible to second-guess the output without seeing the input,.

Comment: `DirectedInfinity` is not a math notion. This is an invention of Mathematica developers.